# Drupal 7 change URL

Tags: url-rewriting, drupal-7

I've recently moved my site to a new domain name which has worked correctly but I have links within content types such as article etc which link to the old URL.

How do I change the links within the content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say manually is the best way.
However if you still own the old domain/site address,you can put up rewrite rules on your web server.
In case you don't you can run a link checker like Xenu on your site.

Answer (score 1):

Use jquery to find the href attributes of links in the content and then you can change the href attributes if you find any links to old domain by some logic to match the old url.